# why my state in redux resets after page refresh

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

created a state using `redux-toolkit` but right after i refresh page or go to another one the state resets. i've been broking my head for 4 hours, can't stand it anymore.
there is code on  [github gists](https://gist.github.com/Bluepuper/bec200d111994fec1b179aedcd410101)

Also here it is:

`index.ts` file: configuration of redux store

```js
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import authStateSlice from "redux/authStateSlice";
import deviceTypeReducer from "redux/deviceTypeSlice";
import userDataSlice from "redux/userDataSlice";

const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    isMobile: deviceTypeReducer,
    isLogin: authStateSlice,
    userData: userDataSlice,
  },
});

export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof store.getState>;
export type AppDispatch = typeof store.dispatch;

export default store;
```

`signin.tsx`: there i fetch data from a server and put it in my redux state:

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useAppSelector } from "lib";
import { useAppDispatch } from "../../lib/useAppDispatch";
import { userActionState } from "redux/userDataSlice";

export const SignIn: React.FC = () => {
  const { isUser } = useAppSelector((state) => state.userData);
  console.log("IS USER: ", isUser);
  const dispatch = useAppDispatch();

  const loginHandler = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch(
        "...link to api",
        {
          method: "POST",
          headers: {
            Accept: "application/json",
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
          },
          body: JSON.stringify({ email, password }),
        }
      );
      if (!response.ok) {
        const err = await response.json();
        throw new Error(err)
      }
      const data = await response.json();

      dispatch(userActionState({ isUser: true }));
    } catch (error) {
        throw new Error(err)
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      ...
    </div>
  );
};
```

`userDataSlice.tsx`: my user's data slice:

```js
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import { ResponseLoginDataType } from "@types";

const initialState: {
  isUser: boolean | undefined;
} = {
  isUser: undefined,
};

const userDataSlice = createSlice({
  name: "isUser",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    userActionState(
      state,
      action: {
        payload: {
          isUser: boolean | undefined;
        };
      }
    ) {
      state.isUser = action.payload.isUser;
    },
  },
});

export default userDataSlice.reducer;
export const { userActionState } = userDataSlice.actions;
```

`userInfo.tsx`: there i tried to get that state, but it gives my default one:

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useAppSelector } from "lib";

export const UserInfo: React.FC<UserInfo> = ({
  name,
  nickname,
  picture,
  activity,
  active,
}) => {
  const { isUser } = useAppSelector((state) => state.userData);
  console.log("USER:: ", isUser);

  return (
    <>
     .....
    </>
  );
};
```

Comment: Do you persist the data anywhere, such as local storage?  Because this sounds like expected behavior.  A single page application works as long as that page is loaded.  Once it's unloaded, all information on that page is gone unless the page persisted it somewhere.

Comment: @David no, isn't that the point of `redux` to keep it even if I refresh the page?

Comment: No, the point of Redux is the centralisation of your application's state.

Comment: @bluepuper no. redux is not a database. Its a tool to manage state. Obviously you can apply db design concepts to manage your state but it is not a persistence data storage. use browser storage to persist your data and hydrate your redux state when app mounts again

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your Redux state doesn't persist to any non-volatile storage, such as local storage or cookies. [redux-persist](https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist) could be an option for you to keep your application's state.

This blog post might help: https://blog.logrocket.com/persist-state-redux-persist-redux-toolkit-react/

Answer (score 1):

When you refresh or leave page, you are restarting the redux store so it will always go back to the default. If you want to persist the store you will need to use a tool like redux-persist. Here is how you could setup your store with redux-persist.

One thing that is annoying is making sure your redux store persists nested objects, secondly since you are in typescript don't try to persist the root reducer.

```
import storage from "redux-persist/lib/storage";
import autoMergeLevel2 from "redux-persist/lib/stateReconciler/autoMergeLevel2";
import persistReducer from "redux-persist/es/persistReducer";
import persistStore from "redux-persist/es/persistStore";

const persistConfigOne = {
  key: "ex1",
  storage,
  stateReconciler: autoMergeLevel1, // Shallow level persisted objects
};
const persistConfigTwo = {
  key: "ex2",
  storage,
  stateReconciler: autoMergeLevel2, // This will persist deeper nested objects if needed.
};

//Can't get state typings if persisting root reducer. Persisted by reducer works.
const reducers = combineReducers({
  ex1: persistReducer<Ex1State, any>(persistConfigOne, ex1Reducer),
  ex2: persistReducer<Ex2State, any>(persistConfigTwo, ex2Reducer),
});

export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: reducers,
  devTools: process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production", // May want to add this for Redux Dev Tools
  middleware: [thunk], // Probably will need to use thunk at some point
});
```